# Microsoft SQL Server Management Studio 17.5 создание нового запроса

Tags: sql-server

В общем, в предыдущих версиях SSMS при создании нового запроса CTRL+N он отображался в обозревателе решений.

Поставил новую версию 17,5 и такое поведение пропало=> если одновременно открыто много запросов и они не помещаются в кладки, то тяжело между ними переключаться.

В предыдущей версии я мог переключаться пользуясь обозревателем решения.

Вот скриншот из предыдущей версии:

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

А вот в новой:
[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Т.е обозреватель пуст и если много запросов, то приходится юзать стрелочку сбоку, что неудобно...

Подскажите, можно ли вернуть подобное поведение?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Нашел решение в виде бесплатного плагина [ApexSQL Complete](https://www.apexsql.com/sql_tools_complete.aspx). В нем есть настройка, которая позволяет вывести список запросов, которые отображаются сверху в список по которому легко выполнять навигацию.

Нашел решение "из коробки", достаточно поставить галку тут:

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]